# How to find rectilinear generators of a surface if it's hard to bring to canonical form?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Find rectilinear generators of a surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2*x*y - 2*x*z - y*z + 4*x + 3*y - 5*z + 4 = 0$ passing through a point $(-1, -1, 1)$.

Is there a way to solve this without simplifying the surface's equation? I tried and got really unpleasant coefficients in resulting equation.

Could somebody please give an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First method (general approach).**

Let

$$H(x,y,z)=x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy - 2xz - yz + 4x + 3y - 5z + 4 = 0\tag{0}$$

The most straightforward way to solve this issue is to find a way to express the given expression under the form

$$H= L_1 \cdot L_2 - L_3 \cdot L_4\tag{1}$$

where the $L_k$ contain at most first degree terms.

Said otherwise :

$$H=0 \ \iff \ L_1 \cdot L_2 = L_3 \cdot L_4\tag{2}$$

How (2) can be used ? The two families $F_1, \ F_2$ of lines **ruling** the surface can be taken in this way :

$$(F_1) \ \begin{cases}L_1&=&a L_3\\ L_2&=&\tfrac{1}{a}L_4\end{cases} \ \ \text{and} \ \ (F_2) \ \begin{cases}L_1&=&b L_4\\ L_2&=&\tfrac{1}{b}L_3\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary non-zero parameters.

Indeed, if for example a point $(x,y,z)$ verifies the two equations in $(F_1)$, it **implies** it verifies the product of these equations, which is nothing else than the equation of quadric $H$. Verb "implies" means "are included" for the corresponding lines into the given surface.

How to find a decomposition of type (1) ? I have obtained one of them by trial and error. But it hasn't taken me a long time, assisted by a Computer Algebra System.

Hint: Here are the factors

$$L_1=x-z+2, \ L_2=x-z+4 $$

I have found. Up to you for finding $L_3$ and $L_4$.

Now, in order to find the equations of the 2 lines,  i.e., to find the value of $a$ and $b$, it suffices to set $(x,y,z)=(-1,-1,1)$ in equations (3).

**Remarks:**

1. The surface with equation (0) is a hyperboloid with one sheet.
2. Decomposition (1) is by no means unique. An example among many: (1) can be written $\ (L_1+cL_4) \cdot L_2 = (L_3+cL_2) \cdot L_4$ for any constant $c$.
3. The fact that, in (3), $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$ gives  two missing lines. Do you see how to compensate that ?

---

**Second method (sketch of)**

Use the fact that the intersection of the tangent plane at

$$(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(-1,-1,1)$$

with the hyperboloid is the union of the two straight lines we want to get.

Please note that the tangent plane is obtained in this way :

$$xx_0+yy_0+zz_0+(xy_0+x_0y)-(xz_0+x_0z)... = 0\tag{4}$$

Then the system formed by (0) and (4) contains all the information.

Comment: Any comment ?...